# Angular run and fail, after cloning github

Tags: angularjs

After successfully Clone Angular Project from GitHub, using git clone ---link. Then when I run "npm install" I found those errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because `uikit` does not export a specific property name `UIkit`.

You should use `import UIkit from 'uikit';` and it should work. Without the `{ }` wrapping.

See [here](https://getuikit.com/docs/webpack) for more

Comment: It doesn't still work even after removing the {} wrapping.

It throws another error which is "ERROR in node_modules/@types/lodash/common/lang.d.ts:578:74 - error TS2677: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.

578         isEmpty<T extends object>(value: T | null | undefined): value is EmptyObjectOf<T> | null | undefined;

Comment: The error it throws is this ""

Comment: so it sounds like you have a different error. You're full of errors, but this solve your current issue you address in the post

Comment: No it didn't @Omri Attiya. But thanks anyway